# what is Ansible wget (similar to puppet Staging::File) to local server

Tags: ansible

I need to download installation files over http to local machine and push to all of my remote machines. What is the best way?

Non of Followings work.

```
 - fetch:
    src: http://www.webserver.com/jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz
    dest: /tmp


 - name: download foo.zip locally
   local_action:
     get_url
     url=http://www.webserver.com/jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz
     dest=files/jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Comment: What's wrong with `get_url` task?

Comment: Your `get_url` syntax is wrong. `get_url` must end in colon and the next lines must be indented.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try that:

```
 - name: download foo.zip locally
   local_action:
     module: get_url
     url: http://www.webserver.com/jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz
     dest: files/jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks Arbab. Looks like "dest" needed absolute path.